# Usage of virtual class and extern in C++

Tags: c++, class, virtual, extern

I've been developing in C++ for some time when I was a student, but I never used virtual class or extern in C++ in any of the projects. I just recent read about these two, and was hoping if someone had a better understanding of their usage.

What is the purpose of virtual class? An example of where it could be used/implemented. I gloss over it a bit on IBM website and wrote a test program to see it in action, but when would it be good to use a virtual class?

The same goes for extern as well. I saw an example, and did a test for myself in C++, but what is the advantage of using extern instead of using a header file? And what is the advantage of a header file instead of extern?

Comment: Do you mean a class that uses virtual inheritance?  Or abstract base classes?

Comment: I was trying to understand when it would be practical to use it. This was the sample I got from IBM website: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr135.htm

Comment: OK, based on the link you provided, you are asking about classes that use virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virtual classes are for when you encounter the [dreaded diamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem). For example:

```
struct Base { int x; };
struct D1 : Base {};
struct D2 : Base {};
struct Derived : D1, D2 {};
```

Here, `Derived` actually has *two* `Base` parts, and as a result *two* member variables called `x`. It will compile, but you might experience some unexpected behaviour when manipulating a `Derived` object through one of its base classes.

```
Derived derived;
D1& d1 = derived;
D2& d2 = derived;
d1.x = 1;
d2.x = 2;
cout << d1.x << d2.x << endl; // 12 !
```

Virtual inheritance solves this problem by making `Derived` derive from `Base` only *once*.

```
struct Base { int x; };
struct D1 : virtual Base {};
struct D2 : virtual Base {};
struct Derived : D1, D2 {};
```

Here, `Derived` only has one `Base` part, and one member variable called `x`.

Comment: Woah! If we covered that back in school, I had completely forgotten about it. What I **do** remember is blanket "Don't use multiple inheritance" statements. +1, I learned something new today, and in a clear and concise manner :-)

Comment: Nice example. I was also taught in school, "don't use multiple inheritance," and was pretty much restricted to it since plenty of courses were Java-based. Thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: As for "don't use multiple inheritance" - I would still stick to that advice in a lot of situations. Virtual inheritance is confusing, and it will just scare people. Try to only use multiple inheritance when only one class has member variables (the rest are empty interfaces).

Answer (score 3):

#### Virtual inheritance

There are no virtual classes, but there's virtual inheritance, and virtually inherited base classes are often called virtual bases.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class IHello
{
public:
    virtual char const* message() const = 0;
};

class HelloImpl
    : public virtual IHello     // Use virtual inheritance for interface
{
public:
    virtual char const* message() const { return "Hello"; }
};

class Abstract
    : public virtual IHello     // Use virtual inheritance for interface
{
public:
    void sayHello() const
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "I'm saying... " << message() << "!" << endl;
    }
};

class Concrete
    : public Abstract
    , public HelloImpl
{};

int main()
{
    Concrete().sayHello();
}
```

Here virtual inheritance has the following effects:

- There is only one base class sub-object of class `IHello`.
- The single sub-object of `IHello` is initialized directly by the most derived class, here `Concrete`.
- The ordinary rules for ambiguous access are slightly amended, so that accessing `message` is OK, and class `HelloImpl` provides an implementation of `message` via *dominance*, sort of like in Java and C# except that it's more general in C++.

If you replace the virtual inheritance with ordinary inheritance, then the above code won't even compile.

#### `extern` versus header files

`extern` and header files are orthogonal concepts.

`extern` says that something has external linkage, and `extern` is part of the language, a keyword.

A header file is a way of packaging code. Usually declarations are placed in header files, so that those declarations can be brought in via a `#include` preprocessor directive. Header files are not part of the language (although the preprocessor is).

So, it does not make sense to "use `extern` instead of a header file".

There is no particular relation, no task for which one could use one instead of the other.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Class is used to remove the diamond shape problem. To better understand this problem consider the scenario

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{

public:
    int i;


};
class B:public A
{

public:

    int j;
};
class C:public A
{

public:

    int k;
};

class D:public B,public C
{
public:
    int l;

};


            A
           / \
          /   \
         B    C
         \    /
          \  /
            D
```

Here B and C inherits A. So the properties (variable and function) exists in both of the class. Again when D inherits Both C and B, then the properties of B and C alongside the properties of A that exists in both the class copied in the class D. So there arise a contradiction. this problem is diamond shape problem.
This can be removed my making the base class A as virtual class which prevent this duplication.
Thanks